# Nested loops of DFT in matlab

Tags: matlab, transform, dft

Can someone explain these nested loops of DFT in matlab:

```
N=length(x);
for k=1:N
  X(k)=0;
  for n=1:N
    X(k)=X(k)+x(n).*exp(-1j.*2.*pi.*(n-1).*(k-1)./N);
  end
end
```

Comment: What is there to explain?

Comment: You probably should look through more simple examples of nested loops, if you don't understand this conception.

Answer (score 4):

The inner loop over `n` is a straightforward implementation of the [Discrete Fourier Transform equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Definition) for a specific frequency bin `k`:

[image]

adjusted for 1-based indexing (as opposed to the 0-based indexing formula from Wikipedia).

The outer loop over `k` simply compute the equation for all `N` frequency bins.

Comment: I normally don't upvote answers on downvoted questions, but I've always loved your signal processing answers. This one especially.  Short and succinct, and brings up the fact about the indexing. +1.

Comment: thanku so much for helping...but the equation in the loop is not same as fourier transform equation., it inputs (n-1 )*  k(-1) instead of n*k.why is that?

Comment: As I mentioned, "adjusted for 1-based indexing". Wikipedia equation uses 0 to N-1. With the change the change of variables n = n'-1 and k = k'-1, you can loop over n' and k' from 1 to N and get the same result. Try writing down a few terms if it helps.